# Raphael JS combined elements with separate control: Removing Event Part 2

Tags: events, raphael

This is a continuation of an earlier thread, that was answered by Neil- thanks Neil!  I probably should have included this in the first question, but I wanted to simplify things...

Another feature that I need is to have a "dialogue box" that holds a title and some text that animates on and off next to the circle when it comes on.  I achieved this in my earlier version prior to the help from Neil. I have spent some time trying to integrate it into the new and improved code and get some unexpected results.  For example, if I rollover the first circle on the right, it works as it should, however, if I try to rollover the middle and right circles, they don't work.  Oddly, if I refresh and start on the right circle, each will work when moving right to left, until I reach the left one, and then the middle and right don't work- but the left one continues to work.  Additionally, if I click on the left circle, it works as it should, but then the others don't work.  And conversely, if I click on the right one first, and then move to the middle, the middle works on click, but then the right one does not.

The behavior that I am looking for is that each circle, animate up with the rectangle next to the circle fading in with dynamic text on mouseover and animate down, with the rectangle with text fading out on mouseout.  The rectangle with text should fade out on click and not fade up again if the user mousesover the clicked circle (need to remove the mouseover event as well I guess).  One additional thing that needs to happen is that the rectangle needs to appear in a different place on the circle, depending where on the map it is- so that it doesn't fall off the map.  I did this successfully in the earlier version, but have left that out on the previous post for better clarity.  I will include it here so you get the gist of what I'm doing.

My guess is that I need to create a set() of the rectangle/text component and place it in an another set() along with the circle?

Any help on this is truly appreciated!  Thanks

```
// JavaScript Document

var arr = [
    [50, 50, "this", "Is text that is to be the abstract"],
    [100, 50, "that", "Is text that I hope is here"],
    [150, 50, "another thing", "Even more text"]
];
var currRect;
var currTitleTxt;
var currTeaseTxt;
var prevItem;

doMe();

function doMe() {
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 696, 348);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    paper.circle(arr[i][0], arr[i][1], 6).attr({
        fill: '#fff',
        'fill-opacity': 0.5
    }).data("i", [arr[i][0], arr[i][1], arr[i][2], arr[i][3]]).click(function () {
        this.unmouseout();
    }).click(function () {
        if (this.data('selected') != 'true') {
            if (prevItem != null) {
                prevItem.data('selected', '');
                handleOutState(prevItem);
            }
            prevItem = this.data('selected', 'true');
            currRect.animate({"fill-opacity":0, "stroke-opacity":0}, 150 );
    currTitleTxt.animate({"fill-opacity":0}, 150 );
    currTeaseTxt.animate({"fill-opacity":0}, 150 );


        }

    }).mouseover(function () {
        handleOverState(this);
        if(this.data("i")[0] <= 350){ //this is where I test for the position on the map
           paper.setStart(); //create rectangle and text set
            currRect =paper.rect(17, -20, 265,90).attr({fill:"#999","fill-opacity":0.5});
            currTitleTxt = paper.text(25, -8, this.data("i")[2]).attr({"text-anchor":"start",fill:'#ffffff',"font-size": 14, "font-weight":"bold","fill-opacity":0});
            currTeaseTxt = paper.text(25, 30).attr({"text-anchor":"start",fill:'#eeeeee',"font-size": 11, "font-weight":"bold","fill-opacity":0});
            var maxWidth = 250;

var content = this.data("i")[3];
var words = content.split(" ");

var tempText = ""; //since Raphael doesn't have native word wrap, I break the line manually
for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
  currTeaseTxt.attr("text", tempText + " " + words[i]);
  if (currTeaseTxt.getBBox().width > maxWidth) {
    tempText += "\n" + words[i];
 } else {
   tempText += " " + words[i];
 }
}

currTeaseTxt.attr("text", tempText.substring(1));

var st = paper.setFinish();
st.translate(this.data("i")[0]+10, this.data("i")[1]+0).animate({"fill-opacity":1}, 150 );

 }else if(this.data("i")[0] >= 351){ //this is where I test for the position on the map
paper.setStart();
currRect = paper.rect(-280, -20, 250,50).attr({fill:"#999","fill-opacity":0.5});
currTitleTxt = paper.text(-270, -10, this.data("i")[2]).attr({"text-anchor":"start",fill:'#ffffff',"font-size": 14, "font-weight":"bold","fill-opacity":0});
currTeaseTxt =paper.text(-270, 5, this.data("i")[3]).attr({"text-anchor":"start",fill:'#cccccc',"font-size": 12, "font-weight":"bold","fill-opacity":0});
var st = paper.setFinish();
st.translate(this.data("i")[0]+10, this.data("i")[1]+0).animate({"fill-opacity":1}, 150 );
       }
    }).mouseout(function () {
        currRect.animate({"fill-opacity":0, "stroke-opacity":0}, 150 );
        currTitleTxt.animate({"fill-opacity":0}, 150 );
        currTeaseTxt.animate({"fill-opacity":0}, 150 );
        if (this.data('selected') != 'true') handleOutState(this);
    });
}

    function handleOverState(el) {
        el.animate({
        r: 8
        }, 250).animate({
        "fill-opacity": 1
        }, 150);

    }

    function handleOutState(el) {
        el.animate({
        r: 6
        }, 250).animate({
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
        }, 150);

    }

}
```